# how do I read from a Database in ruby sinatra using active record

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I want to read entrys from a Database using active_record and keep getting diffrent Errors like: Name error and can't find the database or it can't execute the query.

so my question here is how do i read from a database or execute SQL-queries and for example write the result into a variable?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "sqlite3",
  :database => "test.db"
)


class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end

#ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table :users do |t|
#  t.string :name
#end


class App < Sinatra::Application
end

get '/' do
  output = users.select(:all)
  f = File.open('name','a'); f.write(output); f.close
  #puts  User.first
```

Comment: yes the database is called test.db and the table is called users 
creating the table via the outcommented Migration method works just fine I just don't know how to read data from the table at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the data from the `users` table, you'd simply do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

get '/' do
  @users = User.all
  puts "Grabbed #{@users.size} user(s) from database"
end
```

Comment: This works fine but if I execute this in my scrpit it returns users::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000002e2eb20 but i want to work with a real value like in best case a string how do I get to a string from there ? thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: just change it to `@user = User.last`, now you can do `@user.name` or whatever fields you have on user.